# Optmisation, populate data from memory

Tags: c#, memory, struct

I'm trying to populate objects using read memory. I'm using structure and it goes pretty fast, at least it seems like it.

```
float x = 0;

while (true)
{
    st.Start();

    List<DataChild> DataChildList = new List<DataChild>();
    var Data = Algorithm.Data;
    Data.ChildData.pData = IntPtr.Add(Data.ChildData.pData, 0x20);

    for (int i = 0; i < Data.NumberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        ChildData childData = Data.ChildDatas.ReadValue(i, true);

        if (childData.Render.X != x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Change detected");
            x = childData.Render.X;
                            }
            DataChildList.Add(childData)
        }

        Algorithm.Data.Datas = DataChildList;
        st.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"populated in {st.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds} ms");

        st.Reset();
   }
}
```

There are my structs :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct ChildData
{
  [FieldOffset(0x0)]
  public IntPtr BasePointer;

  [FieldOffset(0x400)]
  public IntPtr pRender;

  public Vector3 Render
  {
    get
    {
     return M.Read<Render>(this.pRender);
    }
  }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Render
{
 [FieldOffset(0x30)]
 public float X;

public float posX
{
  get
  {
   return this.X;
  }
}
}
```

The StopWatch says I populate the data in `0.005 ms.`

When I press a key, it change the value of `childData.Render.X` (the only one in the list for now).

But it displays it in between 0.5 and 1 sec which seems to be very slow compared to speed of the loop.

Have to say that this code is running into a Thread.

Any ideas on why it takes so long? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so the code above is fine and works fast, but some code in something you didn't post takes a long time? Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: @RonBeyer  This loop works pretty fast but when i'm changing data in memory, it should go through the `if (childData.Render.X != x)` (It's in the code I posted) but it happens like 0.5 or 1 second after I changed the data which seems pretty slow.

Comment: Can you post the code in the Render function?  Maybe that's got a lot of or slow code in there.

Comment: My guess would be that Render is some sort of graphing component, and changing the property X is altering some data point, and then generating a whole new graphic to display.  There is usually some way to telling the graphing component not to update whilst you change a lot of the data, and then forcing an update at the end of the loop.    What is the namespace of 'Render' ?

Comment: @Neil I've added my structures

Comment: OK, so you seem to be doing some sort of interop with another process?  this is always going to be slow (maybe not as slow as you are seeing, but certainly slower than native c# data accesses).   What does M.Read<> do?

Comment: casting between `float` and `IntPtr` seems like a really really bad idea.

Comment: @Neil Yeah exactly, I know it's slower but the populating seems fast, that's why i'm wondering. 

Read<> is just reading memory from a process and return the value in the choosen type.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah sorry, It was a mistake from a past code. Changed it by the right one.